# Do you know synonyms of "so-called"?

Tags: synonyms

Do you know any good synonyms of **so-called**? I could not find any synonyms in dictionaries.

Thank you so much.

PS: I'd like to use it to say that a concept is commonly called in an inappropriate way.

Comment: Do you mean the sarcastic usage e.g. 'our so-called leader is drunk again'?

Comment: No, I mean the normal, non-sarcastic usage.

Comment: Sometimes (but not always), ***self-styled*** (and if you want to show off your linguistic skills, you can use the French version ***soi-disant***). But we'd need a lot more detail of the exact context to see how things like *[also] **known as, alias, dubbed, moniker, pseudonym*** would work.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - 'sometimes (but no always)' - yes. But I am intrigued to note that my sense of  _soi-disant_ meaning _qui passe pour ce qu'il n'est pas_ (which pretends to be what it is not) is evolving in modern French into something more like the English 'so-called' (alleged by some to be, but not by me!). Bemoaned by some as unwanted _évolution sémantique_ but approved of, it seems, by the Académie.

Comment: It would be better if you could show an example of how you are using it in a sentence. **So-called** has several possible meanings, and context is everything.

Comment: to completely remove the possible insult in so-called, you can use "what is called".

Comment: Some people would have you believe there are equivalents, perhaps even in this sentence.

Comment: Why do you need a synonym? The normal expression for your intended meaning would be "so-called".

Comment: in certain situations "putative" is correct.  Note that this DOES NOT have the negative connotation. So I'm just bringing it to your attention.  *OED, putative | 
adjective [attributive]
generally considered or reputed to be: the putative author of the book.*

Comment: I don't think there is a 'non-sarcastic' usage. FumbleFingers might be right in saying '… not always self-styled…' and in my view '… not always' will be insignificant here.

I also suggest that your acceptance of the usage  '… that a concept is commonly called in an inappropriate way…' is part of the reason you're Asking for '… synonyms of so-called.'

Comment: *misnomer* or *misnamed*

Answer (score 24):

It is difficult to suggest any direct synonyms because prefixing something with 'so-called' is done for a variety of reasons and can mean slightly different things. It can suggest that you personally disagree with the name, for any number of reasons. It can also suggest that something is inappropriately named, or that something does not live up to its name. It is sometimes used to indicate that something is a given (or taken) name rather than a description - an example of this is when the BBC (and possibly other news agencies) began blanketly referring to the jihadist group Islamic State (IS) as 'the so-called Islamic State' to emphasise that they were not describing the group as either a recognised state or as Islamic, which could offend those who believed they did not represent either.

Some suggestions for different contexts might be:

- the **alleged** solution to the problem did not work.
- the **poorly-named** 'Greatest Show on Earth' was not that great.
- the **supposed** 'best man' gave a terrible speech.

If you are trying to suggest the name is inappropriate you could use almost any adjective, such as *questionably-named, unaptly-named, badly-named* etc.

Comment: Thank you. I realise that further clarification was necessary. I'd like to use it to say that a concept is commonly called in an inappropriate way.

Comment: @wangli - do you mean like 'the so-called koala bear, which is not a bear but a marsupial?'

Comment: @wangli Do you mean you want to refer to a specific concept that has been inappropriately named, or something that has been called a concept when it isn't one?

Comment: Another use of "so-called" you didn't mention is to indicate that the author doesn't expect the reader to already know a term – for instance, popular science articles will often say things like "The distance is estimated using a so-called cosmic distance ladder" if they don't want to give the reader the feeling that they should already know what a cosmic distance ladder  is.

Comment: "Misnamed" would be good for Koala "bears", electric "eels", flying "foxes", star (and jelly) "fish" and many more (thanks to  [Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/story/animals-that-were-named-totally-wrong) for the examples.)

Comment: @CCTO 'misnamed' would suggest either deliberate or accidental misnaming on the part of the namer. It doesn't really cover the most common use of 'so-called' which when another party questions the name or throws shade on it.

Comment: Let's not forget about the "Guinea pigs" and the "Holy Roman Empire" :)

Answer (score 18):

## purported

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/purported

adjective

reputed or claimed; alleged:

*We saw no evidence of his purported wealth.*

Comment: This is the first word I thought of after "alleged." But "purported" is better in this case, I think, because it doesn't carry the connotation of needing to be illegal or undesirable.

Comment: @jrdevdba This is basically the same as 'alleged' which I mentioned. Neither of these words alone are a substitute for all uses of 'so-called' as usually used to denote that something has *yet to be proved*. Your example even supports that. Something could later be proved and cease to be 'purported'.

Comment: @Astralbee Actually I think "alleged" and "purported" differ enough in connotation to prefer one over the other in certain cases. Alleged is accusatory and comes from the accusing side, whereas purported is applied more generally to questioning anything put forward as true or correct. The OP seems to be talking about someone misusing a concept - in that case I would pick purported over alleged, only because alleged is so often used in a legal or criminal sense. 

https://vocabulary-vocabulary.com/dictionary/purported.php

Answer (score 4):

Do you *need* a synonym? Sometimes quotes do as well. To adapt the examples from  @Astralbee

- the "solution" to the problem did not work.
- the 'Greatest Show on Earth' was a bit ordinary.
- the "best" man gave the worst speech.

Comment: For a verbal equivalent, there’s the phrase “[quote-unquote](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quote_unquote)”.

Comment: And there's air quotes !

Comment: This is commonly called [scare quotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scare_quotes). In fact that wikipedia article even says it's used in a way 'similar to preceding a phrase with the expression "so-called"'

Answer (score 4):

putative

> 1: commonly accepted or supposed 
> 2 : assumed to exist or to have existed

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/putative

ostensive or ostensible

> 1: intended for display : open to view
> 2: being such in appearance : plausible rather than demonstrably true or real the ostensible purpose for the trip

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ostensible

There's also "widely believed to be" or "widely accepted".

Answer (score 1):

To highlight that the "actual" (or original) sense of the term does not align with common usage, the word *misnomer* can be useful.

Context is everything. In addition to the other suggestions, *hackneyed* and *much-maligned* might suit the situation.

Nobody uses "beg the question" in the original sense of petitio principii anymore, and everybody nowadays treats it as a synonym of "raise/engender the question." Do I complain? Yes, I do.

Comment: I resent being called “nobody”. 

Comment: @TimPederick Nobody uses “nobody” to mean *nobody* anymore.

Answer (score 0):

[**Soi-disant**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/soi-disant):

> : self-proclaimed, so-called

Comment: I first encountered this phrase in Robert Heinlein's writing. I'm not sure I've ever seen it anywhere else.

Comment: @jeffB It’s rare, but one more recent example was an article mocking a political opponent as hanging out “among the soi-disant sophisticates.”

Comment: "soi-disant sophisticates" is possibly the shortest self-mocking phrase I've yet encountered.

Answer (score 0):

These can be used as alternatives, but they don't strongly imply wrong usage compared to "so-called", apart from no.3:

1. also known as (a.k.a.)
2. colloquially known as
3. mistakenly known as
4. usually known as

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).